# refresh function for treeview wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, refresh, datacontext

I have a treeview:

```
<TreeView Name="files" Margin="0,0,569,108" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding s1}" >
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Members}" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="folder.jpg" Margin="0,0,5,0" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBlock Text=" ["/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Count}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="]"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Content}" Checked="FileCheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="FileCheckBox_Unchecked" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

and I have a function  of select all:

```
private void AllFilesCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Site item in (files.Items).SourceCollection as ObservableCollection<Site>)
    {
        foreach (CheckBox c in item.Members)
            c.IsChecked = true;
    }   
}
```

The problem is that the tree doesn't refresh after the function...

How can I refresh it?

answer:

add IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" in the data template

Comment: If your question was solved, best to add it as a fresh answer. And welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

You could update `ItemsSource` `property`. the implementation of its `method` would look like this:

```
 private void AllFilesCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (Site item in (files.Items).SourceCollection as ObservableCollection<Site>)
        {
            foreach (CheckBox c in item.Members)
                c.IsChecked = true;
        }

        //update your tree view
        var temp = mytreeview.ItemsSource
        mytreeview.ItemsSource = null;
        mytreeview.ItemsSource = temp;
    }
```

Comment: Need to add IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"

Answer (score 0):

add `IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"` in the data template